# Parameters of find command

Tags: find, options

What difference does it make when using the `-print` and `-depth` parameters in `find` command, given that they produce the same outcome:

```
/home/pkaramol/Desktop/testdir
$ find . 
.
./testfile3.txt
./testfile1.txt
./testfile4.txt
./testdir1
./testfile2.txt
./testdir2
/home/pkaramol/Desktop/testdir
$ find . -depth 
./testfile3.txt
./testfile1.txt
./testfile4.txt
./testdir1
./testfile2.txt
./testdir2
.
/home/pkaramol/Desktop/testdir
$ find . -depth -print
./testfile3.txt
./testfile1.txt
./testfile4.txt
./testdir1
./testfile2.txt
./testdir2
.
```

Comment: Only by coincidence. Try on an actual structure.

Comment: This question shows a bemusing lack of any basic research before posting. I ran the essential step 1, `man find`, and trivially searched for these switches to learn what `-depth` does and how it's a no-op here, and how `-print` is the default action and hence redundant in your examples.

Comment: @underscore_d Nitpick: `-depth` is actually not a no-op in this case.  See the ordering of `.` compared to the other pathnames.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-print` will ensure that the current pathname is printed to standard output. Some flags turns off the default printing of pathnames (`-exec` for example).

`-depth` will cause a depth-first traversal of the file hierarchy, so that pathnames in directories without subdirectories are handled first (bottom up rather that top down). In your example, it makes little difference as you are working in directory without subdirectories, but notice that `.` is reported *after* the other pathnames when you use `-depth` (this is since `.` is the top-most directory to be searched, so its pathname is handled last with `-depth` and first without `-depth`).

It is useful to use `-depth` if one is deleting directories with `find` as you would get errors from trying to access already deleted directories without it.

As Scott points out in comments below, you would *definitely* need `-depth` when *renaming* directories too, or you would potentially not be able to traverse the directory structure at the same time as you're renaming directories in it.

The `-delete` flag turns on `-depth` by default.

---

Example:  Delete all directories beneath the current directory whose names matches `*deleteme` (for example `folder-deleteme`), and also print the paths to the successfully deleted directories:

```
find . -depth -type d -name '*deleteme' -exec rm -rf {} ';' -print
```

Given the following directory structure,

```
$ tree
.
`-- folder-deleteme
    `-- another-deleteme
        `-- evenmore-deleteme

3 directories, 0 file
```

executing the above `find` command *without* `-depth` would result in

```
$ find . -type d -name '*deleteme' -exec rm -rf {} ';' -print
./folder-deleteme
find: ./folder-deleteme: No such file or directory
```

because `find` deletes the top-most `folder-deleteme` directory (and prints its path) and then tries to enter it to look for further directories to delete.

Also:

```
$ find .
.
./folder-deleteme
./folder-deleteme/another-deleteme
./folder-deleteme/another-deleteme/evenmore-deleteme

$ find . -depth
./folder-deleteme/another-deleteme/evenmore-deleteme
./folder-deleteme/another-deleteme
./folder-deleteme
.
```

Comment: Am I overlooking something? It looks like the end result of `find . -type d -name '*deleteme' -exec rm -rf {} ';'` is the same with or without `-depth`, except for the error message. *Renaming* directories is (IMHO) a better example of the need for `-depth`.

Comment: @Scott You are not overlooking anything. The error message is the only difference in this example. Yes, _renaming_ directories is definitely another case where `-depth` is needed. I didn't consider that... I will add this (tomorrow, it's too late here now). I'll make a quick note about it now though.